# How to get an 8x8 led matrix pin out?

Tags: led, pinout, led-matrix

I recently bought an 8x8 led array/matrix. I thought all the 8x8 led matrices had the same pinout, but I've found different pinouts. My 8x8 is not for Arduino.

Comment: By reading the data sheet that came with it

Comment: mine came without data sheet :(

Comment: Now you know why you never buy things without a datasheet

Comment: "My 8x8 is not for Arduino"  Why? Its just an 8x8 led display regardless of pin connections.

Comment: @JImDearden: he probably means that it is not specifically marketed for arduino and does likely not have a connector specifically tailored for arduino

Comment: This is a question and answer site, not for show and tell.  Nothing was asked, and if there was, the answer would probably be *"Read the datasheet.  Duh!"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Your 8x8 led matric is going to have a circuit similar to the image above. Though the pinouts may be different. (Check if the pinouts are the same for your LED array as mentioned in the image. Most of them are similar.)

To find the exact pinout, you can use a 5V or 3.3V supply and GND. Connect the supply through a resistance (eg. 330 ohm) to any one pin, and connect all the other pins one after another with the ground. Note the LED's that glow. If no LEDs glow, then reverse the polarity and do it again. You should have 8 LEDs glowing by now.

Repeat this process for all the pins and you will be able to make the pinout for your 8x8 led array (dot matrix) yourself.

You could do this using a multimeter. Set the multimeter in the mode to detect short cirucit. In this mode the multimeter's positive probe is set to a weak 5V supply(So series resistance may not be required) and the other probe is at 0V.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no designation at all on your LED array (a few foto's might have helped!) the only option is to try.

Use a 3 .. 12V power source, a 1 k series resistor, and wires. If you have 16 pins or less (assuming a mono-color display) each pin will have a function. Touch one with one wire, and probe all other with the other. If this doen't light up any LED, use the other wire on the stationary pin and try again. Proceed to find the function of all pins.

For a display with dummy pins (the common 8x8 24-pin displays have 8 pins that are not connected) you might need to try a few more 'stationary' pins untill you find the first combination that lights up a LED.

This procedure finds you the pinout, but not the other specs like the current rating. For common displays you can often assume 20 mA, but YMMV.